Moving the contents of one List to a different List
I want to move the contents of one List to another List but the lists are slightly different.
   List<stuff> Stuff
   List<Parameter> Parameter

These are the classes the lists are of...
 public class Stuff
 {
   public string ItemOne {get;set;}
   public string ItemTwo {get;set;}
 }

List<stuff> would go into this List<Parameter>...

 public class Parameter
 {
   public string name {get;set;}
   public string val {get;set;}
 }

An element would be  name="ItemOne"  value=ItemOne
The name field is the actual string ItemOne etc.
I'm trying it this way but the name has to change with each iteration depending on the element. Also the counter I implemented seems very old fashioned.  There has to be a smooth way to do this?
int counter = 0;
foreach(item in Stuff)
{
  Parameter[counter].name = [whatever the item is]
  Parameter[counter].val = item.[whatever the item is]
  counter++
}

Example: a Stuff object might have the following:
ItemOne = "Spoon",  ItemTwo= "Fork"
The corresponding elements in the List<Parameter> would be...

name="ItemOne"  val="Spoon"  
name="ItemTwo"  val="Fork" 


You tagged this as [tag:c#] but are you actually writing in C#?  Stuff and Parameter are not List<T> lists, or any kind of IEnumerable.  Also, if you really are using C#, what .NET version are you using?

Sorry!  I corrected the confusion

But what about ItemTwo?

If I understand correctly, this  means each Stuff instance will have two Parameter instances. How will you group those within List<Parameter>, to know which Parameter items belong to which Stuff? Seems like you actually need a List<List<Parameter>> or a List<Parameter[]> or similar.

If stuff fields are known beforehand
You can just append them. nameof oeprator will take care to raise compiler error if you change name of the field (and will follow F2-> auto rename as well)
foreach(var stuff in Stuff)
{
  Parameter.Add(new Item { name = nameof(stuff.ItemOne), val = stuff.ItemOne });
  Parameter.Add(new Item { name = nameof(stuff.ItemTwo), val = stuff.ItemTwo });
}

If not
You will need to use reflection to get all fields inside Stuff.
foreach(var stuff in Stuff)
{
  var type = stuff.GetType();
  foreach(var field in type.GetFields()) {
    Parameter.Add(new Item { name = field.Name, val = field.GetValue(stuff).ToString() });
  }
}


Old answer removed.

ItemOne and ItemTwo  are not Name/Value pairs.  The Parameter list should have name="ItemOne"  and val=ItemOne.  Name is the actual string "ItemOne"

Oh I know the stuff fields will always be strings!

@John Yeah, but C# does not know that - GetValue returns boxed object. Calling ToString on boxed string is perfectly fine and will get you underlaying string

List<Parameter> parameters = Stuff
    .SelectMany(stuff => new List<Parameter>
    {
        new Parameter { name = "ItemOne", val = stuff.ItemOne },
        new Parameter { name = "ItemTwo", val = stuff.ItemTwo }
    })
    .ToList();

using this SelectMany extension with LINQ

This could be handled by a simple LINQ select.
var parameters = stuff.Select(s => new Parameter{ name = s.ItemOne, val = s.ItemTwo }).ToList();


I think the OP expects us to infer there is also another Parameter for ItemTwo, so each stuff instance will need to Parameter instances.

That would work if ItemONe and ItemTwo were name/value pairs.  But they each need their own name/value element.

ItemTwo is a string. Just looking at the code you have above. OP please update the code if there is another intention.
